# What kind of math topics exist?

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, online-resources

> What kind of math topics exist?

The question says everything I want to know, but for more details: I enjoy studying mathematics but the problem is that I can't find any information with a summary of all math topics, collected together. I also googled this and took a look at other websites and searched this website but without success.

So if someone knows most of the topics, then please let me know them. The topics I am looking for are the ones from basics, to the university, and beyond university limit. Any comprehensive information you can provide would be useful.

Further thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Areas_of_mathematics

Comment: Before jumping to vote to close, folks: I think the question is clear. **And legitimate**. Certainly "a real question." Just because someone may not have a full mastery of English is no reason to not ask for clarification, if you can't figure out what's being asked.

Comment: @amWhy For president!

Comment: @amWhy: I voted to close because this question is _overly broad_ and I "can imagine an _entire book_ that answers [this] question."  (Proficiency in English had _no bearing whatsoever_ in my decision.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying **now**, @Arthur, I can understand. It would have been good to **say so** (**comment**) *when* you voted to close. May I note that we get many questions about, say, understanding material implication, e.g. why $F \implies F$ is true, about which entire books are written. A very good number of other *legitimate questions* which have **not** been closed are precisely the sorts of questions for which *entire books* have been written.

Comment: @amWhy thanks for being kind to me. And I am sorry if my english language isn't that perfect but hey practice makes perfect and if someone is willing to tell me that I made some mistakes in my writings then he is welcomed to show me them so I can  correct them.
kind regards

Comment: and why @ArthurFischer would you like to close this "question" for it might help people to like me to find what they are looking for or am I wrong at this point?
kind regards

Comment: You're most welcome, Assil. I understood your question just fine! I think he thought that the question is so broad. There is a lot one can say about all the many topics in mathematics, and it's hard to know how exactly what counts as a topic, because there are so many. But as you'll see in the links I provide you, there are many ambitious, but admirable attempts to "organize" comprehensibly all the areas of mathematics.

Comment: @amWhy I am curious about the websites to check them out ...do they also include the math topics which are on the university level and beyond?

Comment: oh yes, indeed, especially the first website. It's how research in math is organized. The second link includes topics you might be more familiar with, what's covered in classes ranging from high-school through university level.

Comment: @Assil: My stance is only that this is a question with incredible breadth. Looking through the links provided in amWhy's answer should give you an idea of how vast a subject mathematics really is. To me your question was like asking for a syntactical synopsis of _all_ the programming languages: something that I don't feel can be reasonably expected to be answered in relatively small space. I wouldn't be surprised if this question is re-opened, at which point it will all in likelihood remain open. At any rate, I hope your future math.SE experiences are less contentious.

Comment: @amWhy I am humbly thankful *bow* for your awesomly good work my dear friend!
Now its time to learn some math^^.
Kind regards assil

Comment: @ArthurFischer I choose especially those kind of words to collect a lot of information about ALL math topics. If I wanted to be specific then I would have asked A LOT of specific questions about a lot of different things in the different areas of math...
Thanks to amWhy I will be able to start to work on my own without asking meaningless "specific" questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the "Princeton Companion to Mathematics" helpful.

[http://www.amazon.com/Princeton-Companion-Mathematics-Timothy-Gowers/dp/0691118809](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691118809)

Answer (score 17):

You might want to start at the [Mathematical Atlas](http://www.math-atlas.org/). It gives a visual map of domains of mathematics, and how they are inter-related: you can click on any "bubble" to learn more about each area. There is also a menu to the right-hand side: for example, see [A Gentle Introduction to the Mathematics Subject Classification Scheme](http://www.math-atlas.org/), also referred to as MSC.

The Mathematics Subject Classification was developed to help categorize *publications* and research in mathematics.

---

See also the entry in Wikipedia: [Lists of Mathematical Topics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_mathematics_topics). This list includes topics which may sound more familiar to you, and groups them together in a sort of classification, each topic with its own link, so you can further explore any/all of them, at your leisure.

> The purpose of this list is not similar to that of the Mathematics Subject Classification formulated by the American Mathematical Society....This list has some items that would not fit in such a classification, such as list of exponential topics and list of factorial and binomial topics, which may surprise the reader with the diversity of their coverage.

Comment: He may also try this website: http://hbpms.blogspot.com/.

Comment: Nice contribution (your link), @Samama ! Thanks for posting it! I haven't encountered this one, before.